# Border line appear in drawable in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, nine-patch

Hello I am trying to get Nine patch drawable from this tool [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html), it generated the drawables of different density and that drawable I am setting as background of the button but drawables it generated has border line around images in four side that appear also when I am trying to run application in device.

Why it is so and can you please tell how this can avoided ?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_views_vertical_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_up_via_email_selector" />
```

sign_up_via_email_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sign_up_submit" />

</selector>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here you apply wrong patch that y it show you border please see this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the image has the correct name.

It should be **sign_up_submit.9.png**, the lines that appear are actually the areas that the 9patch defines for stretch.

If the image has the correct name it is a chance that the online utility application you used messed the resource. Try to use the 9patch generator from the android sdk(look for ***[your_sdk_path]\tools\draw9patch.bat***), and try to generate one yourself and see if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

can you please check how you placed your 9 patch image in drawable folder,9 patch image should be named sign_up_submit.9.png